# Excel shows duplicate merge columns

Tags: python, excel

I have a issue writing to excel after merging.

```
Outfile1 = r’k:\dir1\outfile1.xlsx’ 
DF0 = [‘A’, ‘B’, ‘C’]
DF1 = [‘A’, ‘B’, ‘D’]

DF2 = DF0.merge(DF1, on = [‘A’, ‘B’])
DF2.to_excel(Outfile1, engine = ‘xlsxwriter’)
```

Excel file has the following columns:

`‘A’ ‘B’ ‘A’ ‘B’ ‘C’ ‘D’  the second ‘A’ & ‘B’ are blank.`

What am I doing wrong?  I only want `‘A’ ‘B’ ‘C’ ‘D’` in spreadsheet.

Comment: I think there is a coding issue, can you share the actual code or somehow close to it? or tweak below to reproduce it `df1=pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],columns=['A','B','C'])
df2=pd.DataFrame([[7,7,7],[1,2,8]],columns=['A','B','D'])
df_merge=df1.merge(df2,on=['A','B'])`

Comment: adding a pic of actual code and output.  Not able to upload code from corp computer.  The code runs to completion without errors.  The only issue is the additional highlighted columns.  There seems to be an issue with the reindex.  if I run code with reindex I get the expected number of columns just not in the order I would like.

Comment: See Pic of code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RY5w.png.   See pic of output : https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSB6J.png

Comment: okay, the only thing I can guess is indexing is not okay. can you try `UP_rollup4.reset_index(inplace=True)` just before  column order(i.e line 73).

Comment: That did the trick, Thank you very much.

Comment: glad that it helped. You are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Conclusion: a**fter merge , its recommended that reset the index otherwise sometime
reindex creates extra columns in output.

**Step 1**: dataset

```
df1=pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],columns=['A','B','C']) 
df2=pd.DataFrame([[7,7,7],[1,2,8]],columns=['A','B','D']) 
df_merge=df1.merge(df2,on=['A','B'])
```

**Step 2** , reset_index before reorder the dataframe through reindex.

```
my_col_order=['D','B','C']
df_merge.reset_index(inplace=True) # after merge , its recommended that reset the index otherwise sometime 
#reindex creates extra columns in output.
df_5=df_merge.reindex(my_col_order,axis='columns')
```

Answer (score 1):

this should do it.

```
import pandas as pd
// data
data = {'letters':['a', 'e', 'c', 'g', 'h', 'b']}
data1 = {'letters':['a', 'd', 'b', 'e', 'f',]}
// data to df
df0 = pd.DataFrame(data)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
// merge
df2 = df0.merge(df1, how='outer')
```

now they are merged without duplicates, but out of order.  Use sort_values to correct this

```
df2 = df2.sort_values(['letters'])
print(df2)
```